# Using lda2vec library with other types of wordvectors

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, lda

Hi I'm new to `NLP` field and recently got interested in `lda2vec`.

After reading [moody's article about `lda2vec`](https://github.com/cemoody/lda2vec/tree/master/docs), I've tried to use the code he posted, but customize wordvector generation parts.

I'd like to use pretrained embeddings and have no idea where I should fix 
since I'm not good at coding too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As is, your question is too broad and would be better addressed by a tutorial. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to re-type online tutorials for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Robert I'll try to work on my code and ask specific question!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the class [corpus](https://github.com/cemoody/lda2vec/blob/master/lda2vec/corpus.py#L483), especialy [this](https://github.com/cemoody/lda2vec/blob/b7f4642b750c6e792c07d177bd57ad36e65bb35c/lda2vec/corpus.py#L483) method:

```
def compact_word_vectors(self, vocab, filename=None, array=None, top=20000):
    ...
    # code is omitted
```

From a doctring, argument filename is a *"Filename for SpaCy-compatible word vectors or if use_spacy=False then uses word2vec vectors via gensim."*

Try to set pre-trained word-vectors with this method. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for guide! I had no idea where to start

Comment: @S.B Do you have any code now? Or just have planned to start?